# Regex pattern using OR

Tags: regex, vb.net

Using patter like this

```
Dim regex As New Regex("#(\d{4}$)")
```

With this pattern i can read value from string

```
My #1234 number
My #125542 Number
```

But what about

```
This is my # 1234 number
This is #12345R number
```

My regex pattern should retrive values.

```
1234
125542
1234
12345
```

Comment: What do you want the match to be? All numbers greater than 4 digits?

Comment: Match only numbers. I give my desired output bellow

Comment: @programerAnel what language are you using? python?

Comment: What programming language is this in? Please tag it in your question.

Comment: @SPYBUG96 vb.NET

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
Dim regex As New Regex("#\s*(\d{4,})")
```

And when you obtain the match grab `match.Groups(1).Value`.

**Pattern details**

- `#` - a `#` char
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(\d{4,})` - Group 1: four or more digits.

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%23%5cs*%28%5cd%7b4%2c%7d%29&i=My+%231234+number%0d%0aMy+%23125542+Number%0d%0aThis+is+my+%23+1234+number%0d%0aThis+is+%2312345R+number), results:

[image]

See the [VB.NET demo](http://rextester.com/IZQI37299):

```
Dim r As New Regex("#\s*(\d{4,})")
Dim s As String
s = "My #1234 number, My #125542 Number, This is my # 1234 number, This is #12345R number"
For Each m As Match In r.Matches(s)
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups(1).Value)
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

.NET supports non-fixed-width lookbehind, so this problem can be solved more directly than in other languages. You can make a full match on what you're looking for, rather than returning the contents of a capture group.

`(?<=# ?)\d{4,}`

http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%23+%3f%29%5cd%7b4%2c%7d&i=My+%231234+number%0d%0aMy+%23125542+Number%0d%0aThis+is+my+%23+1234+number%0d%0aThis+is+%2312345R+number

Comment: Can you give me a sample for 4+ digits only. No matter does it have # or not . Just 4+ numbers in sequence

Comment: I'm confused--in your comment on another answer you said that the number needs to come after a `#`. If all you need is 4+ numbers regardless of what appears around them, you can just use `\d{4,}`.

Comment: @CAustin Yes in case i dont find it with # in front i would use this to find 4 nubers without #

Comment: Ok, well there you go. Your pattern is just `\d{4,}`

Answer (score 1):

In python you can do something like this.

```
re.search("(\#) ?(\d{4,})", arg).group(2)
```

This will match with all numbers greater than 4 digits that start with a #, but only returns the number

---

This will match with all numbers of any length only returning the numbers

```
re.search("(\#) ?(\d+)", arg).group(2)
```

**NOTE:** This answer was written before the asker specified the language they were programming in

Comment: Numbers need to be after # mark .. Posible two solutions #Number and #[Space]Number

Comment: @programerAnel Sorry based on the inputs you provided in your description this should work, unless you have more numbers in the strings you are matching with. Can you provide us with a couple more input examples with all of the possible cases?

Comment: #1234,#12345, # 1234, #12345R My outputs should be 1234,12345

Comment: This answer doesn't account for the possible space. Also, why is there a capture group around the `#`, and why is the `#` escaped with a back slash?

Comment: @CAustin For the first part, Must have missed the info about the space(easy fix). And I like grouping my regex's, just personal preference. I though the # was a special character so I escaped it

Comment: In that case, why isn't there a group around the space now? Sorry, but the grouping thing is just bad practice. It's not just redundant code--it affects the order of your capture groups, and if someone else were to read your code they'd probably be confused by why the purpose of the extra group is.

Comment: @CAustin So the way my code is now, the space isn't another capture group. Thanks for the heads up though about it being a bad practice. I am a development team of 1 with no one around to do code reviews